# Cannot std::move from lambda capture to function call inside lambda, why?

Tags: c++, c++14

In the following code

```
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <utility>

void f1(std::unique_ptr<int>&& uptr) {}

void f(std::unique_ptr<int>&& uptr)
{
    auto thread = std::thread([uptr{ std::move(uptr) }]() {
        f1(std::move(uptr));
    });
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

the call to `std::move` inside the lambda cannot be compiled:

```
[x86-64 gcc 8.1 #1] error: binding reference of type'std::unique_ptr<int>&&'
to 'std::remove_reference<const> std::unique_ptr<int>&>::type'
{aka 'const std::unique_ptr<int>'} discards qualifiers
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/g/9dQhEX

Why does this error occur and how can I fix it? Where does `const` come from?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to make the lamdba `mutable` as the closure variables are `const`-qualified by default.

```
auto thread = std::thread([uptr{ std::move(uptr) }]() mutable {
                                                    //^^^^^^

     f1(std::move(uptr)); /* Works, no constness-violation.*/
 });
```

Comment: "the closure variables are const-qualified by default" - I didn't know that, thanks!

Comment: One of the few places where `const`-ness is default. I wish it were more.

Comment: life-saver. i spent ages trying to work this out.

Answer (score 5):

You should make lambda state mutable:

```
auto thread = std::thread([uptr{ std::move(uptr) }]() mutable
```